# How to ReLoad a load() without supplying a URL

Tags: jquery

using `.load(url)`, but is there an Ajax `.reload()` function that can be used without having to supply a URL as you have to do using `.load(url)`?

Comment: 1) No, there is not, and 2) Why on earth would you need that anyway?

Comment: Why not just save the URL that was used the first time using `.data("origURL", url)` and then you can reload at any time by just using the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no way to load ajax data without giving url. but if you want, you can store ajax response to a JavaScript variable and then second time load data from the variable. (or use html container tag)